# Swift Converting Data to double give me wrong value

Tags: swift, double, byte, floating

I have a Data with a list of bytes :
[64, 69, 207, 65, 61, 225, 199, 151]
hex string is equals : 4045cf413de1c797
I'm getting bytes with this function :
var bytes: [UInt64] = data.map { UInt64(bitPattern: Int64($0)) }
data is a Data type

when i convert it to a double i'm getting wrong value
I tried several function to convert it :

Example 1 :

```
 extension Data {
 enum Endianess {
    case little
    case big
}

func toFloat(endianess: Endianess = .little) -> Float? {
    guard self.count <= 4 else { return nil }

    switch endianess {
    case .big:
        let data = [UInt8](repeating: 0x00, count: 4-self.count) + self
        return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }
    case .little:
        let data = self + [UInt8](repeating: 0x00, count: 4-self.count)
        return data.reversed().withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) }
    }
    }
    }
```

This one gives me Nil

Example 2 :

```
        var f:Float = 0.0
        memcpy(&f, bytes, 4)
```

The result  : 8.96831017167883e-44

Example 3:

```
       let floatNb:Float = dataSliced.reversed().withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: 
       Float.self) 
       }
```

The result : 0.11024397

without reversed() i'm getting error :
Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer

Example 4 :

```
  extension Numeric {
   init<D: DataProtocol>(_ data: D) {
    var value: Self = .zero
    let size = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, { data.copyBytes(to: $0)} )
    //assert(size == MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value))
    self = value
  }
  }
```

Result is : -4.089067083288947e-194

The good result is : 43.61917851948163

How can i convert properly a Data to double ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this worked by separating Int and Double like this  :
For double :

```
   let bytes: [UInt16] = dataSliced.map { UInt16(bitPattern: Int16($0)) }
    dump(bytes)
    if(bytes.count == 8){
        var hexValue = dataSliced.toHex()
        hexValue = "0x\(hexValue)"
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexValue)
        
        var decimalValue: UInt64 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&decimalValue)
        
        doubleValue = Double(bitPattern: decimalValue)
        print("doubleValue \(doubleValue)")
```

For Int

```
    let decimalValue = dataSliced.reduce(0) { value, byte in
        return value << 8 | Int(byte)
    }
    return decimalValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that as destination you are using `Float` instead of `Double`. `Float` is using only first 4 bytes.

```
let bytes = [UInt8](arrayLiteral: 64, 69, 207, 65, 61, 225, 199, 151)

let result = bytes.reversed().withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(
        as:Double.self
    )
}

assert(43.61917851948163 == result, "invalid result \(result)")
```

Comment: @tamtoum1987 it's success in my playground

Comment: @tamtoum1987 may be you are using `[UInt64]` instead of `[UInt8]`?

Comment: I was using UInt64 because i need a generic solution if i use UInt8 i'm getting error for this bytes (table of 4 bytes) Thread 1: Fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds

Comment: @tamtoum1987 for `[UInt64]` it will be `let bytes = [UInt64](arrayLiteral: 0x4045cf413de1c797) ` and you don't need to reverse it.